# count and print the frequency of '0', '1' and 'NA' in each row after the header row

Tags: awk

```
Chr     start   stop    superfamily     TE      pres/abs        88      108     139     159     265     350     351     403     410     424     428     430     506     544     546     6
1       8667    8700    MuDR    ATDNAI27T9A     presence        NA      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       NA      0       0       0       0
1       10585   10600   Gypsy   ATHILA6A        presence        NA      0       0       0       0       NA      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1       15091   15099   Copia   ATCOPIA13       presence        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1       15894   15898   Gypsy   ATGP1   presence        0       0       NA      0       NA      0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       NA      1
1       20514   20532   MuDR    VANDAL8 presence        NA      0       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      1       0       NA      NA      NA      0       0       0       NA      NA
1       20530   20537   Gypsy   ATGP1   presence        NA      0       0       NA      NA      NA      NA      1       0       NA      NA      NA      0       0       0       NA      NA
```

Following is what i tried to get the frequency of '0' and '1'

```
cat file.bed|awk '{if(NR>1){for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if($i==0)print}}'|awk '{count=0;if(NR==1){print $0"\tcount"}else{for (i=8; i<=NF; i++){if ($i==1){count++}}print $0"\t"count}}' > x
```

My code is not giving me the right output

How can I correct my code so that I get three columns added in the end of my output file which gives me the count of 0, 1 and NA?

0, NA and 1 need to be counted second row and onwards. In columns 0, NA and 1 need to be counted seventh column and onwards

Desired output:

```
Chr     start   stop    superfamily     TE      pres/abs        88      108     139     159     265     350     351     403     410     424     428     430     506     544     546     6 count0 count1 countNA freq0 freq1 freqNA 
1       8667    8700    MuDR    ATDNAI27T9A     presence        NA      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       NA      0       0       0       0 14 0 2 0.87 0 0.12
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing: Do you want to count for all fields or only in fields that have a number as a header? Using `print` prints the whole line and not the field. What is the output you expect (Just `number of 0 = 12` etc?). Counts for the whole file or per line? Should the counts be new colums? Please me more specific.

Comment: "My code is not giving me the right output" ... Please [edit] your question to show what the correct output should be.

Comment: You seem to be mixing frequency and count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==1 { print $0, "0s", "1s", "NAs" }
     NR>1  { for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) { NAs+=$i=="NA"; ones+=$i==1; total++ };
             print $0, total-ones-NAs, ones, NAs; NAs=ones=total=0;
}' infile >outfile
```

`NAs` variable counts the occurrences of "NA"s.
`ones` variable counts the occurrences of the "1"s.
`total` counts the total visited fields from 7<sup>th</sup>-last fields (this could be removed but I used for clarity<sup>*</sup>).
`total-ones-NAs` is the count of "0"s (by subtracting ones&NAs from total).
`NAs=ones=total=0` resets the variables for the next line.

---

*<sup>*: we could remove `total++` and replace `total-ones-NAs` with `NF-6-ones-NAs`.</sup>*

Comment: awk awk_script > output. Is this the usage of script?

Comment: @Gavin If you save the script in an external file, it should look like `awk -f script.awk infile > outfile`